# In python, 13 and 9 = what?

Tags: python, boolean

Boolean operator 'and' returns `True` if both sides are `True`. Any number other than 0 is True. So python should return `True` for

```
13 and 19
```

But why does it return 19?

Comment: Python "should" is just your opinion. What it does is a fact. If you really care about being a "true" boolean, [`bool(13 and 19)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) is right there.

Comment: Both "19" and "9" are true, so in essence it's doing what you want.  ;)  That's the key.  Python uses "truthy values" more than the literal `True`.

Answer (score 0):

> The expression **x and y** first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

in simple words if x is `0` it will return `0` else it will return `y`

Answer (score 0):

> Boolean operator `and` returns `True` if both sides are `True`

This is the case if both sides are literally `True` as in `True and True` is, not surprisingly, `True`. For other values they are *truthful* or not, in which case, the last value in the chain is the value propagated.<sup>1</sup>

This is because you do not always want a boolean. `test = x and "works!" or "nope"` would be annoying if it returned a boolean and "ate" your string.

If you *really* want a boolean, you can cast with `bool()` which will convert from *truthful* to `True` and otherwise to `False`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Many languages follow this tradition where the types have a *truthful* state, like Ruby (`13 and 19` yields 19) and JavaScript (`13 && 19` yields `19`). If Python's behaviour differed significantly from that it would likely cause uproar as this is the *expected* behaviour.